# Firebase - Keep user logged in when they close app

Tags: firebase, firebasesimplelogin, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to keep the user logged in if they close the app on their phone, so they don't have to input their login details every time?

Comment: Firebase for Android and iOS keep the token of the logged in user in local storage. So they already will survive an app restart. You're probably doing something wrong in the way you wire up the auth, but it's impossible to say what without an mcve (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You'll probably be helped by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32904910/how-deal-with-cold-start-of-an-app-where-user-has-beeing-logged-with-firebase-at

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen